# Oracle sum previous values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sum

I´m trying to do the the following: With this table:

```
DATE       VAR       
---------------
 2011      2.82          
 2012     -3.47        
 2013     -5.8        
 2014      13
```

I need to obtain this other table:

```
 DATE    VAR       ACUM    
---------------------------------------
 2011    2.82         
 2012   -3.47     -0.65      
 2013   -5.8      -6.45      
 2014    13        6.55
```

i.e. i nedd another column with the VAR value plus the sum of the all previous values.

```
for the 2014 row....13-5.8-3.47+2.82 = 6.55
for the 2013 row....-5.8-3.47+2.82 = -6.45
```

and so on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Sum() Over()` trick to find the running total

```
SELECT "DATE",
       VAR,
       Sum(VAR)OVER(ORDER BY "DATE") as ACUM
FROM   Yourtable
```

Or `correlated subquery`

```
SELECT "DATE",
       VAR,
       (SELECT Sum(VAR)
        FROM   Yourtable b
        WHERE  a."DATE" > b."DATE") ACUM
FROM   Yourtable a
```

Do not use **DATE** as column name, you would have to enclose it within double quotes all the time. And you also make it case sensitive by doing so. Bad idea.

Comment: Perfect!!!, i didn´t know this window option for the sum function. ¡Thank you very much!

Comment: The correlated subquery would return NULL for first row.

Comment: Hey, sorry, perhaps that is what OP wants, to be NULL.

Comment: Alternatively you could use the lead or lag functions.  And yeah don't name columns after reserved words.